# bindtomoniker java equivalent in COM

Tags: java, com, jacob, indesign-server

I have used the Java Jacob library to communicate with inedesign server application which exposes a COM interface. Normally you would communicate via a clsid or programid.Eg -

```
this.gApp = new ActiveXComponent("Indesign.Application");
```

So far so good. But when there are more than one named instances of the indesign server application, the docs state that communication should be via the application instance name instead of the clsid/programid. This does not work with the above listed line of code.
For C#, the docs suggest using -

```
InDesignServer.Application app = (InDesignServer.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(instancename);
```

For VB -

```
GetObject(instancename);
```

Is there a library in Java which supports this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating many libraries, COM4J had what I required.